# How do I import rxjs operators from a centralized file for jasmine unit tests in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have a file: `src/app/shared/rxjs-imports.ts` that adds my rxjs operators. For example:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

The `rxjs-imports.ts` file gets imported in my `app.module.ts` file so that my application has a single import of necessary rxjs operators during run time. But how do I import that same file at the right time before my jasmine unit tests start so that I don't get the various missing operator errors during testing that complain that `map` and `from` (etc) can't be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `src/test.ts`:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';

import {getTestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
}                   from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

You'll notice the line that imports all spec files: `require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`.

If you create an adjacent `test.spec.ts` file, it will be loaded last, but its imports and definitions will take place before any of your tests run. Problem solved.

As a bonus, it's also a convenient location to place hooks you want to load before starting your first test:

```
// Put anything you wanted loaded before your tests start here

import './app/shared/rxjs-imports';

beforeAll(() => {

});

afterAll(() => {

});

beforeEach(() => {

});

afterEach(() => {

});
```

Because all `spec` files are loaded, even if you tell jasmine to focus on a single test, and because you are not scoping anything in this file within a jasmine `describe` function, any before/after hooks you place here will  be applied to all your tests.